# Faddeev-Popov Determinant of Chern-Simons Theory

Tags: quantum-field-theory, gauge-theory, topological-field-theory, chern-simons-theory

I am asking this question in order to figure out the expression of the Faddeev-Popov determinant given by Edward Witten is his paper "[Quantum Field Theory and Jones Polynomial](https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.cmp/1104178138)".

Starting from the action

$$S[A]=\frac{k}{4\pi}\int_{M}\mathrm{Tr}\left(A\wedge dA+\frac{2}{3}A\wedge A\wedge A\right)$$

the variation gives equation of motion

$$F=dA+A\wedge A=0$$

Denoting the solutions to the equation of motion by $a$, then one expands a generic connection $A$ around a flat connection

$$A=a+B$$

Then the action splits into three pieces:

$$S[A]=\frac{k}{4\pi}\int_{M}\mathrm{Tr}\left(a\wedge da+\frac{2}{3}a\wedge a\wedge a\wedge a\right)+\frac{k}{4\pi}\int_{M}\mathrm{Tr}\left(B\wedge D_{a}B\right)+$$

$$+\frac{k}{6\pi}\int_{M}\mathrm{Tr}\left(B\wedge B\wedge B\right)$$

where the covariant derivative in the second term is defined as $D_{a}=d+[a,\,\,\,\,]$.

The gauge transformation $A[U]=U^{-1}dU+U^{-1}AU$ splits into two parts:

$$a[U]=U^{-1}dU+U^{-1}aU,\quad B[U]=U^{-1}BU$$

so that the flat connections remain flat and the perturbation part $B$ lives in the adjoint representation.

Then, the path-integral takes the form

$$Z=\int\mathcal{D}a\,e^{iS[a]}\int\mathcal{D}B\,\exp\left\{\frac{ik}{4\pi}\int_{M}\mathrm{Tr}(B\wedge D_{a}B)+\frac{ik}{6\pi}\int_{M}\mathrm{Tr}(B\wedge B\wedge B)\right\}$$

It's easy to check that the last two terms

$$S[a;B]=\frac{ik}{4\pi}\int_{M}\mathrm{Tr}(B\wedge D_{a}B)+\frac{ik}{6\pi}\int_{M}\mathrm{Tr}(B\wedge B\wedge B)$$

are indeed invariant under the gauge transformations $a[U]=U^{-1}dU+U^{-1}aU$ and $B[U]=U^{-1}BU$. Assuming the spacetime manifold $M$ is closed, and $k\in\mathbb{Z}$, then the first part

$$S[a]==\frac{k}{4\pi}\int_{M}\mathrm{Tr}\left(a\wedge da+\frac{2}{3}a\wedge a\wedge a\right)$$

is also gauge invariant up to a shift by $2\pi\mathbb{Z}$ from the Wess-Zumino-Witten term under large gauge transformations.

Assuming that the moduli space of flat connections $\mathcal{M}=\mathrm{Hom}(\pi_{1}(M),G)/G$ is a discrete set, then the partition function really is

$$Z=\sum_{m\in\mathcal{M}}e^{iS[a_{m}]}\frac{1}{\mathrm{Vol}}\int\mathcal{D}B\,\exp\left\{\frac{ik}{4\pi}\int_{M}\mathrm{Tr}(B\wedge D_{a}B)+\frac{ik}{6\pi}\int_{M}\mathrm{Tr}(B\wedge B\wedge B)\right\}$$

To fix the gauge, the author imposes the covariant gauge

$$\mathcal{F}[a;B]=(D_{a})_{\mu}B^{\mu}=0$$

The Faddeev-Popov determinant is then

$$\Delta[a;B]=\mathrm{Det}\left(\frac{\delta\mathcal{F}[a[U];B[U]]}{\delta U}\right)\Bigg|_{U=\mathrm{id}}=\mathrm{Det}(M)$$

Using chain rule, one has

$$M(x-y)=\int d^{3}z\left\{\frac{\delta\mathcal{F}(x)}{\delta B(z)}\frac{\delta B(z)}{\delta U(y)}+\frac{\delta\mathcal{F}(x)}{\delta a(z)}\frac{\delta a(z)}{\delta U(y)}\right\}$$

***In Witten's paper, the final expression of the Faddeev-Popov is quite simple, which is
$$M=(D_{a})_{\mu}(D_{a})^{\mu}$$***

***However, carrying on the calculation of functional derivatives, I obtained a quite different result.***

To be specific, the functional derivatives are given by

$$\frac{\delta\mathcal{F}(x)}{\delta B(z)}=D_{a}(x)\delta(x-z),\quad \frac{\delta\mathcal{F}(x)}{\delta a(z)}=[\delta(x-z),B(z)]$$

$$\frac{\delta B(z)}{\delta U(y)}=[B(z),\delta(z-y)],\quad \frac{\delta a(z)}{\delta U(y)}=D_{a}(z)\delta(z-y)$$

where $(D_{a})_{\mu}(x)\delta(x-y)=\frac{\partial}{\partial x^{\mu}}\delta(x-y)+[a_{\mu}(x),\delta(x-y)]$, and the commutator here carries Lie-algebra indices and so is symmetric. i.e. $[A,B]=AB+BA$.

Plugging the above functional derivatives back into the determinant, what I obtained in the end is $$M(x)=4(D_{a})_{\mu}B^{\mu}(x)$$

This is obviously incorrect.

What am I mistaken in the above procedure?

(I also posted this question [here](https://www.physicsoverflow.org/41428))

Comment: As for the problem of flat connections, you may find [The Hilbert space of Chern-Simons on a torus, part one.](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/415254/84967) useful.

Comment: As a side comment, please note that the Ray-Singer torsion in that paper has a minor mistake -- it should be the square root of the Ray-Singer torsion, as has been pointed out in [link](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/BF02100006)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Witten wants to evaluate the path integral for a given background $a$, he doesn't want to vary $a$ inside the $B$ action.  If he had wanted to do so he wouldn't have chosen the gauge fixing $(D_{a})_{\mu}B^{\mu}=0$, because this gauge fixing is invariant under the combined gauge transformation of $a$ and $B$ given in the question.

The action for the fluctuation field has the following gauge freedom:
$$ a[U] = a$$
$$B[U] = U^{-1}BU + U^{-1}D_aU$$
(Infinitesimally: $\delta B[U] = D_a \delta U + [ B, \delta U] = D_A \delta U$)

Please notice that the Chern-Simons action for $B$ is gauge invariant with respect to the above transformation, since $D_a$ is nilpotent due to the flatness of $a$:
$$D_a^2 = F_a = 0$$
Thus we have a gauge theory of the non-Abelian $B$ gauge potential with the exterior derivative $d$ replaced by the twisted differential $D_a$.

Now, we have :
$$\delta\mathcal{F}[a;B]=(D_{a})_{\mu}\delta B^{\mu}=  (D_{a})_{\mu}(D_A)^{\mu} \delta U$$

Thus the Faddeev-Popov Laplacian is:

$$M=(D_{a})_{\mu}(D_{A})^{\mu}$$

Please notice that this is different from Witten's result, the second covariant derivative is with respect to the full gauge potential: background $+$fluctuation. We get Witten's result only if we assume that the fluctuations are small and neglect terms higher than the quadratic term. This fact was noticed by [Birmingham,  Blau, Rakowski  and Thompson](http://cds.cern.ch/record/218572/files/CM-P00062470.pdf), where a careful evaluation is given in equations 6.14 and 6.15 on page 195.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help Mr David Bar Moshe. This problem made me suffer from insomnia. Oh, stupid me. Thank you for illuminating me.

Comment: Hi Sir. I have one more question for you. The fluctuation part of the action under the above gauge transformation then produces a "covariant version" of Wess-Zumino-Witten term, which is $\mathrm{Tr}(U^{-1}D_{a}U\wedge U^{-1}D_{a}U\wedge U^{-1}D_{a}U)$. Is this still integral?

Comment: Yes, it should be. The reason is that the twisted exterior differential $D_a$ acts on the various fields according to their representation. For example $\mathrm{Tr}\left(( U^{-1} dU)^3\right)$ is a scalar, therefore:  $D_a\mathrm{Tr}\left(( U^{-1} dU)^3\right) = d\mathrm{Tr}\left(( U^{-1} dU)^3\right) $, thus: $d\mathrm{Tr}\left(( U^{-1} dU)^3\right) = \mathrm{Tr}D_a\left(( U^{-1} dU)^3\right) = 0$. The vanishing of the last term can be proved according the same criteria of the standard WZW term. Thus this form is closed.

Comment: Therefore on a compact manifold we can find a normalization which makes it integral. Now, this normalization should not depend on the flat connection $a$ at least when its moduli space is connected. Thus if we start from $a=0$, we get the usual normalization which should persist for all values of $a$ on the connected component of $a=0$.

Comment: Hi Mr David Bar Moshe. Do you mean $\mathrm{Tr}D_{a}((D^{-1}D_{a}U)^{3})$?

Comment: Hi Sir. Would you tell me how $D_{a}$ acting on $U$ is defined? Is that just $dU+aU$?

Comment: $U$ transforms under the adjoint representation, therefore, $D_a U = dU + aU – Ua$. Another example: suppose that you have a matter field $\Psi$ transforming according some general transformation represented by the matrices $\{T_i\}$. Then $D_a \Psi = d\psi + a_i T_i \Psi$. The WZW term is a (gauge group) scalar, then $D_a (WZW) = d (WZW)$ (in other words $\{T_i\}$ are all zero for the WZW term (trivial representation)).

Comment: How can $U$ transform in adjoint representation? U is a gauge transformation, so it is a scalar function.

Comment: All objects in the Yang-Mills theory operate on a Cartesian product: space-time $\otimes$ internal symmetry. $U$ is a space-time scalar but it is a group element of the internal symmetry. In all what I mentioned above I referred to the internal symmetry.

Comment: But from the infinitesimal gauge transformation, it should be $D_{a}U=dU+aU$.

Comment: If $U$ had belonged to the fundamental representation, for example, then your equation would be correct. Please check that under the transformation: $U\rightarrow V^{-1}UV$ and $a\rightarrow V^{-1}aV+V^{-1}dV$, that the derivative that you wrote is not covariant, while the derivative given above with the adjoint action is covariant.

Comment: Hi Sir I am sorry I still cannot understand. What is $U\rightarrow V^{-1}UV$? From the equation $D_{a}U=dU+aU$, it is obvious that the variation of $U^{-1}D_{a}U$ produces the infinitesimal term $D_{a}\delta U$.

Comment: It is a gauge transformation, I'll write it  in your notation: Make the transformation: $U[V] =  V^{-1}UV$ and $a[V] =  V^{-1}aV+V^{-1}dV.  $ Now, is $D_a$ covariant under this transformation? i.e., does the following equation hold: $D_{ a[V] }(U[V]) = V^{-1} (D_a U) V$, now you can perform your check, which expression of $D_a$ satisfies the above transformation rule.

Comment: $U$ belongs to the gauge group, while $a$ belongs to the Lie algebra. I don't think $[a,U]$ makes sense.

Comment: I understand that $U^{-1}dU$ is the Mauri-Cartan form, which is Lie algebra-valued. Does it make sense to write $U^{-1}D_{a}U$? Does this form have any geometric meaning?

Comment: The whole WZW theory is given when the group elements $U$ are given as matrices in the fundamental representation. The trace in the WZW functional is in the fundamental representation. Please, see in the following article, how Witten uses these commutators of a Lie algebra element with a group element (for example on page 428, the fifth line in the text). The physical meaning of such kind of a commutator is an infinitesimal gauge transformation on a finite group element.
http://www.phys.sinica.edu.tw/~spring8/users/jychen/pub/reference/NPB_v223_422.pdf